# Using two dataset same map R ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want to have two different data set on the same map with ggmap. The problem is that when I try to superpose both datasets, it keeps erasing the first one. Any idea how to solve this?

Dataset1 would be for example the number of patent per city in a country and Dataset2 would be the size of universities in the same country.

My code is:

```
    map.ma <- get_map(location = 'Massachusetts', zoom = 8, color="bw")
    mapPoints <- ggmap(map.ma) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = (sbir.cities1$SBIR)), data = sbir.cities1, alpha = .5, color="red")
    mapPoints2 <- mapPoints + scale_size_area(breaks = (c(1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500)), labels = c(1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500), name = "SBIR")
    mapPoints3 <- mapPoints2 + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, size = sqrt(ma.universities1$Enrollment)), data = ma.universities1, alpha = .5, color="blue")
    mapPoints4 <- mapPoints3 + scale_size_area(breaks = sqrt(c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000)), labels = c(5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000), name = "Enrollment")
    mapPoints4
```

My datasets are:

```
    structure(list(X = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), name = c("Acton", "Amesbury", 
"Amherst", "Andover", "Arlington"), SBIR = c(7L, 2L, 13L, 265L, 
6L), country.etc = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("#N/A", 
"MA"), class = "factor"), pop = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 24L, 
10L), .Label = c("#N/A", "101342", "103085", "133313", "152095", 
"177973", "40063", "40441", "40565", "41246", "41520", "44473", 
"44690", "45127", "50698", "53579", "55066", "55862", "567759", 
"57377", "58407", "60784", "65103", "67715", "74802", "84969", 
"93128", "94039", "94945"), class = "factor"), lati = c(42.29, 
42.51, 42.23, 42.65, 42.42), long = c(-71.26, -70.55, -72.31, 
-71.14, -71.16), capital = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("#N/A", 
"0", "2"), class = "factor"), geocode = c("Acton Massachusetts", 
"Amesbury Massachusetts", "Amherst Massachusetts", "Andover Massachusetts", 
"Arlington Massachusetts"), lon = c(-71.43284, -70.9300376, -72.517, 
-71.1367953, -71.1564729), lat = c(42.4850931, 42.8583925, 42.367, 
42.6583356, 42.4153925)), .Names = c("X", "name", "SBIR", "country.etc", 
"pop", "lati", "long", "capital", "geocode", "lon", "lat"), row.names = c(89L, 
128L, 72L, 135L, 123L), class = "data.frame")
```

and:

```
    structure(list(School = c("Boston University", "University of Massachusetts Amherst", 
"Harvard University", "Northeastern University", "University of Massachusetts Lowell"
), Location = structure(c(5L, 1L, 11L, 5L, 28L), .Label = c("Amherst", 
"Andover", "Bedford", "Beverly", "Boston", "Bourne", "Bridgewater", 
"Brighton", "Brockton", "Brookline", "Cambridge", "Chestnut Hill", 
"Chicopee", "Conway", "Dartmouth", "Dudley", "Easton", "Fall River", 
"Fitchburg", "Framingham", "Franklin", "Gardner", "Great Barrington", 
"Greenfield", "Haverhill", "Holyoke", "Longmeadow", "Lowell", 
"Lynn", "Medford", "Milton", "Needham", "Newton", "North Adams", 
"North Andover", "Northampton", "Norton", "Paxton", "Pittsfield", 
"Quincy", "Roxbury", "Salem", "South Hadley", "South Hamilton", 
"Springfield", "Swampscott", "Turners Falls", "Waltham", "Wellesley", 
"Wenham", "West Barnstable", "Westfield", "Weston", "Williamstown", 
"Worcester"), class = "factor"), Control = structure(c(2L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("For-profit", "Private", "Public"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("Associate\325s college", 
    "Baccalaureate college", "Baccalaureate/associate's college", 
    "Master's", "Master's university", "Master\325s university", 
    "Research university", "Special-focus institution"), class = "factor"), 
    Enrollment = c(32603L, 28518L, 28147L, 20053L, 16932L), geocode = c("Boston University Massachusetts", 
    "University of Massachusetts Amherst Massachusetts", "Harvard University Massachusetts", 
    "Northeastern University Massachusetts", "University of Massachusetts Lowell Massachusetts"
    ), lon = c(-71.1053991, -72.5267121, -71.1166601, -71.0891717, 
    -71.3340665), lat = c(42.3504997, 42.3911569, 42.3770029, 
    42.3398067, 42.6426529)), .Names = c("School", "Location", 
"Control", "Type", "Enrollment", "geocode", "lon", "lat"), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you be able to provide your data? You are more likely to receive help when you can provide your code and sample data.

Comment: Thanks Jazzurro, do you know how can I upload my two datasets?

Comment: One way is to use `dput(yourdataname)`. If you type that in R Console, you will see texts on the screen. You want to copy and paste that in your question. If your data is large, you may want to minimise it.

Comment: Thanks I added the data frames with only the first five rows.

Comment: Hi, I finally got time to look into this. I guess what you are asking is to keep two legends in the graphic. Is that right?

Comment: Hi Jazzurro, yes, I would like to keep the two legends and have the two layers superposed on the map.